# Any Alternatives to retchmail

Tags: ubuntu, email

I am a long time user of retchmail. Today i upgraded my server to ubuntu 12.04 from Debian Lenny after everything is complete retchmail does not exist for 12.04.

Are there any alternatives to retchmail, which can do parallel multiple mailbox mail fetching.

I use retchmail to retrieve mail for 100+ users from their respective mail boxes to local zimbra server, so users get a 100+ Mbps connection instead of relying on a slow internet connection.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When [retchmail was removed from Debian](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=488004#26), mpop ([Debian](http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=mpop), [Ubuntu](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=mpop)) was recommended as a replacement.